# why is my data undefined when i make an http request?

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have a problem with my backend when I send my data to the API req.body sends me null {}
 suddenly I don't understand why I can't recover my data, however on the front side I send the data well ?

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you included a body parser for your express app? Try adding the line app.use(express.json()) above your routes

Comment: Please do not paste code as images, include them as text.

Comment: sorry for the layout

suddenly I added the bodyparser but still the same problem

Comment: console.log your variables and check which is falsy

Comment: Please share the code how you *send* the request. Also, it would be best to paste the code here instead of showing images as images will eventually get deleted by third-party providers.

Comment: variables are  undifined

Comment: public onFormSubmit() {
 
  const configUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/users/register';
  this.http.post(configUrl,this.signupForm.value)
  .subscribe(results => {
    this.results = results;
  });
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

if you're using form data then include url encoded parser like this::

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended : true}));
app.use(express.json());
```

add this in your main server file where you create your server

Answer (score -1):

It may be the order of variables, haven't tried, but that is the only thing that sticks out. When you are sending its {email,name,password2,password} but when you are receiving it its {name,email,password,password2}

Edit: messed up variable orders when replying ironically

Comment: The order is not important when using object desctructuring (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring).